# Create a view integrating previous views in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I created three views in my new database using data from AdventureWorks2014. All three views compile and save just fine, there are no problems with them. However, when I try to make one full view including all three, nothing seems to be working.

Views `creation`, `creation2` and `creation3`:

```
ALTER VIEW [creation] AS
SELECT sd.ProductID, YEAR(sh.OrderDate) AS 'Year',
 MONTH(sh.OrderDate)AS 'Month', DAY(sh.OrderDate) AS 'Day',
sd.UnitPrice AS 'Value', sd.OrderQty AS 'Quantity', NULL AS 'col7',
NULL AS 'col8'
FROM AW2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS sh
INNER JOIN AW2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sd
ON sd.SalesOrderID = sh.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Sales.Customer AS c
ON c.CustomerID = sh.CustomerID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Person.Person AS p
ON p.BusinessEntityID = c.PersonID
WHERE p.PersonType LIKE 'IN'

ALTER VIEW [creation2]AS
SELECT p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName,
CONCAT(a.AddressLine1, ' ',a.AddressLine2,', ',a.City) AS 'Address',
cr.Name, NULL AS 'col6', NULL AS 'col7', NULL AS 'col8'
FROM AW2014.Person.Person AS p
INNER JOIN AW2014.Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea
ON p.BusinessEntityID= bea.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Person.Address AS a
ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Person.StateProvince AS sp
ON a.StateProvinceID = sp.StateProvinceID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Person.CountryRegion AS cr
ON sp.CountryRegionCode = cr.CountryRegionCode
WHERE p.PersonType LIKE 'IN'

ALTER VIEW [creation3] AS
SELECT DISTINCT p1.ProductID, p1.Name AS 'Product', pc.Name AS 'Category', 
sc.Name AS 'Subcategory',
p1.StandardCost, p1.Color, p1.Weight, CONCAT(p1.SizeUnitMeasureCode,', ',p1.WeightUnitMeasureCode) AS 'Units'
FROM AW2014.Production.Product AS p1
INNER JOIN AW2014.Production.ProductSubcategory AS sc
ON p1.ProductSubcategoryID = sc.ProductSubcategoryID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Production.ProductCategory AS pc
ON pc.ProductCategoryID = sc.ProductCategoryID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sd
ON p1.ProductID = sd.ProductID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS sh
ON sd.SalesOrderID = sh.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Sales.Customer AS c
ON sh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
INNER JOIN AW2014.Person.Person AS p
ON c.PersonID = p.BusinessEntityID
WHERE p.PersonType LIKE 'IN'
```

I made every view have the same amount of columns, as I've read on stack I should if I want to use `union` statement. I did it like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [a] AS
SELECT * FROM [creation2]
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [creation]
```

and I get a message that my command was completed successfully. Yet when I try to `SELECT * FROM [a]`, it executes endlessly with no results. After checking `dbo.a` in the drop down menu, the only columns it has are the ones from the first view (in this instance, `creation2`). It's as if it ignores (or can't execute?) the `union` or `union all` statements.

I tried using `JOIN` as well, adding a `p.PersonType` column to each of the views, and joining them on those. It worked just fine as long as I was only selecting them, but when I tried to put them into a new view, I was getting an error that a view should have distinct columns. I can't make it distinct if I want to join them all on it, can I? 
Either way, my question stands - how can I put all three of my views into a new one, considering all these options above have failed me? Maybe you have some tips, maybe I made some dumb mistakes in my code? I used SQL before but years ago, and I'd love any tips on improvement as well.

I'm using Microsoft SQLServer Management Studio 2017 btw. Thank you!

Comment: Your code is fine.  The views are working.  The optimizations are just not what you expect.  The returned rows tend to come from the first view . . . you might have to scroll (a lot) to see more.

Comment: You can’t Union things with different columns and types. Strange that the view was even created if they’re not the same. Maybe you could explain what you’re trying to achieve rather than wonder why this isn’t working, especially if you’re trying unions and joins which are very different things.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes but I have nowhere to scroll? The new view [a] doesn't even show me anything. It doesn't execute when I select it. And in the drop down menu of my database I can clearly see all the columns(there's only 8 of them) and they're just from [creation2] :(

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yeah of course! What I'm trying to achieve is create a new view, let's call it [a], which will have all columns from all 3 views [creation], [creation2] and [creation3]. When I've been looking for solutions online everyone said to use union, and it should work as long as there's the same number of columns in each view I'm trying to include. So, is there any way to maybe convert all columns in each view to the same type so I could union them into [a]? Without losing the data? I hope this clears up my intentions...

Comment: UNION is for the situation where you combine data from different sources that have the same columns. For example first and last name from three sources. Here you don’t have that, the data is different. So you most likely want a JOIN between them. You just have to define how you want to join them together, meaning which columns are equal to each other between the tables. Assuming that would be table Person since it’s in each of them.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, alright, I'd like to do that, but as I said in the question, I'm stuck on what should I join. I tried putting PersonType column in all of them and I was able to join them on `creation.PersonType = creation2.PersonType` but then the new view wouldn't create bc the columns were redundant. How else could I join it? There are no other common columns between them, and if I create them, won't they be redundant as well? Is there a way to join them on PersonType since they all use it with the `where` clause, but don't have the column in them? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `UNION ALL`, you should join on columns exposed by the 3 views since it isn't appropriate to concatenate results of unrelated views.

You can't use `SELECT *` for a view when that results in duplicate column names. It's a best practice to specify an explicit column list anyway and, when needed, specify a column alias to distinguish column returned from different tables. I also suggest meaningful view names like the example above as that will make it easier to understand the relationships for proper querying.

To use views easily in queries with joins, each view should generally expose one or more columns that uniquely identify a row (like a primary key in a table). `PersonType` isn't unique in any of the views so that would result in a many-to-many join and return lot of rows. That join doesn't make logical sense in this case. Joins should generally be a one-to-one or one-to many relationship.